# UIImage not being received via first view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

Hi there i currently have just "think i have cracked sending content through a prepare for segue" but the problem is that my images are not showing up in the second view controller. As I'm kind of new to this i would like to know if there is something that i am missing because no matter what i can't seem to get the image of my first view controller to show in my second view controller.

GroupsViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface GroupsViewController : UIViewController<UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate> 
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *GroupsCollectionView;

- (IBAction)cellToggleAction:(id)sender;

@end
```

GroupsViewController.m

```
#import "GroupsViewController.h"
#import "GroupsHomeViewController.h"
#import "CustomCell.h"


@interface GroupsViewController ()
{
    NSArray *arrayOfImages;
    NSArray *arrayOfDescriptions;
}

@end

@implementation GroupsViewController
{
    NSString *reuseIdentifier;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[self GroupsCollectionView]setDataSource:self];
    [[self GroupsCollectionView]setDelegate:self];
    reuseIdentifier= @"SmallIcon"; //set inital value of reuse identifier

    arrayOfImages = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"a.png", nil];

    arrayOfDescriptions = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"A", nil];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [arrayOfDescriptions count];
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [[cell IconImage]setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[arrayOfImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]]];
    [[cell IconLabel]setText:[arrayOfDescriptions objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];
    return cell;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"GroupsHomeSegue" sender:indexPath];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"GroupsHomeSegue"])
    {
        NSIndexPath* indexPath = [[self.GroupsCollectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems]firstObject];
        if(indexPath !=nil)
        {
            //NSString *selectedDescription = arrayOfDescriptions[indexPath.item]; //collects description from cell
            NSString *selectedImage = arrayOfImages [indexPath.item]; //collects image from cell

            GroupsHomeViewController *groupsHomeViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
            groupsHomeViewController.logoImage = [UIImage imageNamed: selectedImage];
            //groupsHomeViewController.groupLabel = [:selectedDescription];

        }
    }
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        //Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

@end
```

GroupsHomeViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface GroupsHomeViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImage *logoImage;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *groupLabel;

@end
```

GroupsHomeViewController.m

```
#import "GroupsHomeViewController.h"

@interface GroupsHomeViewController ()

@end

@implementation GroupsHomeViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Thank You in advance for your kind help.

Comment: Try passing the string alone. Just to debug if the NSString is being logged in the second UIViewController.

Comment: Nothing seems to be happening during debug, complete blank screen. Is there something i need to turn on to show what the code is doing?

Comment: Set a breakpoint and debug the same?

Comment: Thats exactly what i did, set a break point in my code and started a debug session. Absolutely nothing appears.

Comment: Where did you set the breakpoint? viewDidLoad?

Comment: I put the break point just before the -(void)didRecieveMemoryWarning is this incorrect?

Comment: Put the breakpoint at [super viewDidLoad]. What you did also makes sense. Isn't the breakpoint being called?

Comment: i have added the breakpoint and now as soon as i load the page it goes off showing me a list of things under thread 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113078/discussion-between-anil-and-lee-sugden).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lee Sugden,

Passing an image is not enough :) If you want it to show on your screen you should load it in an ImageView isn't it :)

Now either create UIImageView programmatically or add a imageView in your story board draw an IBOutlet and set the image as

```
self.yourImageView.image = self.logoImage;
```

else create an UIImageView programmatically as,

```
UIImageView *yourImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.logoImage.size.width,self.logoImage.size.height)];
  yourImageView.image = self.logoImage;
  [self.view addSubview:yourImageView];
```

Comment: So what i have done so far is correct as far as sending the image but i need to add code to my second view controller to receive the image as such so that i can display it?

Comment: @LeeSugden : You have already received the image buddy :) now all you have to do is to write a code to show it in UI :) if you are using story board or xib add a UIImageView draw a IBOutlet and just write one statement I wrote on top :) If you are not using both of them create a imageView programmatically and add it as subView to your View :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in your `GroupsHomeViewController`. You need a `UIImageView` as your `IBOutlet` rather than a `UIImage`, then you need to set the `image` property on the image view to your desired image. To do this, you need to update your `GroupsHomeViewController.h` file like so:

```
@interface GroupsHomeViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *logoImageView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *logoImage;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *groupLabel;

@end
```

And then in your `GroupsHomeViewController.m`, set your image view's image in the `viewWillAppear`:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.logoImageView.image = self.logoImage;
}
```

Now, when you set `logoImage` in your segue, the image view will load the image just before the view appears.

This is assuming that you have the image view already on your storyboard with the outlet correctly connected.

Answer (score 0):

I think the guys above may have solved this with the advice to set the image to whatever image view is holding it. But if that still hasn't solved it, with prepareForSegue, I've had problems due to iOS voodoo where the variable isn't set. So to be sure, override the setter in your GroupsHomeViewController.m to make sure the object is properly assigned to your image property.

```
- (void)setLogoImage:(UIImage *)logoImage
{
    _logoImage = logoImage;
}
```